# 'vector' does not name a type

Tags: c++, vector, namespaces

I'm fairly new to C++, & am having a problem with declaring vectors as a class variable. I've got them to work elsewhere in my code by using a similar strategy, but it doesn't like my header file.

```
error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
error: ‘vector’ has not been declared
error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
```

I've commented the lines which GCC points out as being a problem.

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using std::string;

//  Class declarations

class Node {
    int id;
    string type;
public:
    Node(int, string);
    int get_id();
    string get_type();
    string print();
};

class Event {
    string name, date, time;
public:
    Event(string, string, string);
    string get_name();
    string get_date();
    string get_time();
    string print();
};

class Course {
    char id;
    std::vector<Node*> nodes[40];     // This one
public:
    Course(char, std::vector<Node*>); // This one
    char get_id();
    std::vector<Node*> get_nodes();   // & this one.
    string print();
};


class Entrant {
        int id;
        Course* course;
        string name;
    public:
        Entrant(int, char, string);
        int get_id();
        Course* get_course();
        string get_name();
        string print();
    };

    //  Function declarations

void menu_main();

void nodes_load();
void event_create();
void entrant_create();
void course_create();


#endif  /* HEADER_H */
```

[Here's a screenshot](http://imgur.com/uutPSOx) of the error in my IDE, if that gives any more clues.

Comment: http://liveworkspace.org/code/40cuIA$1 all is ok... There was only one error about unknown type Course (forward declaration fix it).

Comment: Have you tried to include this header in a clean main method alone? My best guess is that this is caused by the includer and not the include itself.

Comment: I've tried including it in a clean main file - generated by Netbeans - & I still get the same errors.

Answer (score 3):

The only problem I could see from actually compiling your code is that you use `Course` in `Entrant` class but you have no definition for `Course` at that point.

If you forward declare `Course` just above `Entrant` like so:

```
class Course;

class Entrant { }; //class definition
```

Then your code compiles, per this [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/309uU7%243)

Comment: Fixed this, though it wasn't the course of the errors, it's a useful hint, cheers.

Comment: @Psygnosys well, it's hard to fix something with code posted that doesn't reproduce the actual problem.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand why this doesn't reproduce the problem, as the error message points to this header file, & those lines :S

Answer (score 3):

You are cheating ;-) . The code you gave to us has `std::vector`, which works, while the code in your screenshot has `vector` which doesn't work (the compiler doesn't know where to get it from).

Solution: Change your code to use `std::vector`.

Comment: Another possible solution is to add

    using namespace std;

to the code.

Comment: @EugeneB That is not a good solution. The resulting namespace pollution *will* get you into trouble sooner or later.

Comment: I have never considered myself as an expert, though I think for simple programs this is better than carrying std:: everywhere. Though, it my opinion only. It might be just a matter of style and habits.

Answer (score 0):

have you installed the stl? maybe this will help you http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1261897

Comment: I'd be amazed if someone managed to install a C++ compiler without the `std` library!

Comment: I've got Ubuntu 12.10, I'd be surprised if it didn't have it either. I followed the guide regardless, as it didn't have the folder specified. Nothing's changed though.

Comment: That link reflects a fundamental misunderstanding that arises from the sloppy use of "STL" to refer to the C++ Standard Library. There's no need for add-ons if you use standard library objects and functions. `std::vector` is part of the C++ Standard Library.